# Create model thumbnails with filament

Tags: c++, graphics, google-filament

When starting from mesh data, i.e. I have a model specified in a "collection of triangles" format, it's pretty straightforward to render it with [filament](https://github.com/google/filament). But is it possible to use [filament](https://github.com/google/filament) to create thumbnail images for such a model?

Ideally I'd be able to specify (or automatically compute):

- Pose (the transformation matrix of the camera viewing the model)
- Material(s)

If not with filament, is there a C++ graphics engine that allows me to easily "flush" my scene into a png?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/google/filament/discussions/5073) gives you some clues for android.